# How to upgrade qBittorrent to the latest stable (upstream) version?

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, qbittorrent

I currently have the 2.9.7 version of qBittorrent.

I want to upgrade to the latest version, 3.0.8.

`sudo apt-get upgrade qbittorrent` returns that the program is up-to-date:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And install after removal do nothing but reinstall version 2.9.7!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The version of [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/) in Ubuntu is always quite old (since it's updated regularly and [most feature and minor bugfix updates don't make it into the official Ubuntu version](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates)).

#### But there is an easy solution!

qBittorrent's maintainer ([sledgehammer999](https://launchpad.net/~sledgehammer-999)) maintains [a PPA providing stable qBittorrent builds](https://launchpad.net/~qbittorrent-team/+archive/ubuntu/qbittorrent-stable). I recommend using that.

To enable this PPA and install qBittorrent from it (or upgrade the version you currently have to the version it provides), open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

(Or you can run `sudo apt-get upgrade` in place of the third line--if some version of qBittorrent is already installed from Ubuntu packages, both ways work.)

I use qBittorrent from that PPA--it works great.

***Source:*** [qBittorrent Downloads page](http://www.qbittorrent.org/download.php) (**Other Binary Packages** section)

For more information on PPAs, see:

- [PPA (Ubuntu community documentation)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA)
- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: This is out of date. Mine won't update to 4.4.x and stays at 4.3.9....the repo isn't kept up to date. Like I can 4.4 there but it may not be set at the newest. It is stable. Information above is out of date.